# virtualenv envname -p=python35 shows error "python35 not found"

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I am trying to create a env for python3.5 using virtualenv on Fedora. I have python37, python27 and python35 installed. When I am trying to run the following command to create a env for python35:

```
virtualenv envname -p=python35
```

it shows following error:

```
The path =python35 (from --python==python35) does not exist
```

But doing :

```
which python35
```

returns :

```
/usr/bin/python35
```

I don't know where the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `virtualenv --help` then you will see something like below:

```
$ virtualenv --help
Usage: virtualenv [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose         Increase verbosity.
  -q, --quiet           Decrease verbosity.
  -p PYTHON_EXE, --python=PYTHON_EXE
```

So as you can see `-p` and python executable have a space between them. If you use long form then you can use `--python=python35`.

So if you change your commend to `virtualenv envname -p python35` then it should work.